# Random error in exe_common.inl in Debug build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets

I am using VS 2022 Community Edition (v17.3.3) to build wxWidgets application (v3.2.0) using C++ (v14.3 - Features from Latest C++). The windows SDK is using the latest installed (10.0.22621). The project is also using C++ modules.

The Debug build succeeds but when I run the project's exe file at random it throws the exception (*Access violation reading 0xFFFFFF (ucrtbased.dll)*) in **exe_common.inl** at the following line:

`__scrt_current_native_startup_state = __scrt_native_startup_state::initialized;`

After a few more compilations (by just making minor changes to trigger a compilation) it succeeds and the exe runs correctly.

I wonder if there is any settings that might be causing this random error. Btw, I am using Win11 but same thing happens on Win10 as well.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

The project is using boost libraries and at startup boost/json (boost/json is used in other parts of the project as well). Debugger shows that after the following line the above error happens:

```
static allocator_arg_t allocator_arg = BOOST_CONTAINER_DOC1ST(unspecified, *std_allocator_arg_holder<>::dummy);
```

Comment: Have you tried investigating the issue using your [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) yet? If not, then that should be your first thing to do.

Comment: Yes, that's where the debugger stops at `__scrt_current_native_startup_state = __scrt_native_startup_state::initialized;`

Comment: If you unwind the stack frames (in the stack frame window) do you get back to your code ?  If so inspect the variables in that stack frame.

Comment: @RichardCritten: I think this problem has started since switching to modules in C++ and currently trialing on disabling "multi-processor compilation" and so far the problem did not happen "yet".

Comment: @macroland, can you try to build with earlier version of MSVC? I think there was a post recently that proves the version is buggy...

Comment: @Igor: The project uses several features of C++20 so would be very hard to try with earlier versions. "So far" I am quite convinced that "multi-processor compilation" and modules (I am using module partitions) might cause some trouble, not sure though.

Comment: The error still happens but its frequency is less, so turning off "multi-processor compilation" helped to some extent but not completely solved the problem.

Comment: I found that the OS you are using is windows11 but using the win10 SDK, I suggest you install and use the win11 SDK.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT: It is Win11 SDK, check https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few things needed attention:

1. Discontinued use of `wxSQLite` (the library was not maintained for over a decade),
2. The main frame was a singleton data structure, not anymore, and not deriving from wxMDIFrame anymore.
3. All unnecessary (a chain of them) `#include` removed.
4. Inclusion of `<boost/json.hpp>` in a few files were removed and now using `#include <boost/json/src.hpp>` only in one .cpp file. However, the project still uses inclusion of  `<boost/json/value.hpp>` in multiple .h files.
5. All uninitialized pointer variables and others were initialized.

#1 and #4 were especially pointed by the debugger. It has now been more than a few days and haven't had the problem since then.